# haskell optparse-applicative: parsing a list of records that have multiple fields

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative, command-line-arguments

If I have the following types and parser:

```
data Mode = 
     Mode1 
   | Mode2 
   deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

data ThingINeedMulitpleOf = 
   Thing { _name :: String, _mode :: Mode }
   deriving (Show, Eq)

thingParser :: Parser ThingINeedMulitpleOf
thingParser = Thing <$> strArgument (metavar "NAME")
                    <*> option auto (long "mode" <> metavar "MODE")
```

and I build a parser in the following way:

```
data Config = 
   Config ThingINeedMulitpleOf ThingINeedMulitpleOf
   deriving (Show, Eq)

loadConfig = execParser $ info (Config <$> thingParser <*> thingParser) fullDesc
```

then I can successfully parse `my-exe Thing1 --mode Mode1 Thing2 --mode Mode2` but this is only useful if I want exactly two `Things`.
I'm running into problems when trying to change the `Config` to support *n* `Thing`s, ie:

```
data Config = 
   Config [ThingINeedMulitpleOf]
   deriving (Show, Eq)

loadConfig = execParser $ info (Config <$> many thingParser) fullDesc
```

but I can now no longer parse `my-exe Thing1 --mode Mode1 Thing2 --mode Mode2`, giving me the error `Invalid argument 'Thing1'`

Interestingly, this works if the `ThingINeedMulitpleOf` only contains one field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a subparser with the `Alternative` typeclass's `some` function, you can get the effect you're looking for, admittedly with a slightly different command line syntax.

```
thingSubparser :: Parser ThingINeedMulitpleOf
thingSubparser = subparser $ command "thing" (info thingParser mempty)

loadConfig :: IO Config
loadConfig = execParser $ info (Config <$> some thingSubparser) fullDesc
```

With this you can write command lines like:

```
my-exe thing test --mode Mode1 thing test2 --mode Mode2
```

which yield the Config object:

```
Config [Thing {_name = "test", _mode = Mode1},Thing {_name = "test2", _mode = Mode2}]
```

I'm not quite sure why you need the subparser and can't just use `some` against the `thingParser`, but if I had to guess it'd be because the command gives the parser a delimiter (the "thing" argument/command name).